# how to exportmysqldump via command line with polygon data

Tags: mysql, geometry, command, polygon

I would like to export my table that have geometry data that's polygon into .sql file via command line i try to use command :

```
mysql -u root -p db_name > C:\Users\iser_name\Documents\dump\geometry.sql
```

the result of inserting data of polygon is something line encode/decode text, and I only know to convert to hex binary. how I can export via mysqldump via cmd but the insert data result is general text like POLYGON(-09.90990,09.09900) etc.

what is should add to the command line?